# LED not working on GPIO pin

Tags: gpio

[image]

Better image - https://vertostudio.com/img/delme_wires.jpg

Please help. I'm beyond utterly fried here.  Did I burn out the pins or something?

Nothing I can do, nothing will light up my led.  I've tried enabling every pin I can think of and doing gpio readall to verify.  I've plugged the cables every which way they can go (maybe this burned out the pins, I dunno), but the pi seems fine.

`+-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 |  OUT | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 |  OUT | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |  OUT | 1 |  7 || 8  | 0 | IN   | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | IN   | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |  OUT | 1 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 1 | OUT  | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 1 | OUT  | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI | ALT0 | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO | ALT0 | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK | ALT0 | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | OUT  | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | OUT  | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |  OUT | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | OUT  | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |  OUT | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |  OUT | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |  OUT | 1 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+`

Resister is 100 OHM.  LED is 3mm.  I've checked and checked and double checked the wiring.

Comment: I can't even see a LED in your image, let alone tell how it is connected. Describe what you have connected and what code you are using.

Comment: Did you connect the LED with the correct polarity? Try to reverse it.

Comment: image:  https://vertostudio.com/img/delme_wires.jpg

Comment: Please edit your title to reflect the actual question. The current title is of little use to anybody searching for this post in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is your breadboard, but below are some instructions for testing for the common problems.

If you look at the power rails (the outer two columns - marked by red and blue lines), they are not continuous from top to bottom of the board, but broken in the middle. There are two quick fixes, move the  LED and wiring to only use the top half of the board or insert wires two bridge both halves of the board (you should probably do this with a red and blue wire and on both the right and left sides of the board. If you want to confirm my suspicion and have a meter you can check for continuity at both ends of the yellow wire.

You may also have the ribbon cable connected to your breadboard backward, you can check this by measuring the voltage between the 5 Volt and ground pins of the red adapter board mounted in your breadboard.

The last thing to check is the direction of the LED. LED's have polarity (like a battery) and will not work if inserted backward. The longer leg is the anode (and connects to the positive side).

Comment: That did it.  I love you.  You can tell I haven't messed with breadboards since my first year in CS.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Your welcome. Don't feel bad not all breadboards have the break, and I fell prey to this when I was just starting out in electronics.